# Get Child components constants/state in parent component in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component which is a MUI TAB like this

```
<Box sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
  <Box sx={{ borderBottom: 1, borderColor: "divider" }}>
    <Tabs
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      aria-label="basic tabs example"
    >
      <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
      <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
      <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
    </Tabs>
  </Box>
  <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
    <Child1 />
  </TabPanel>
  <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
    <Child2 />
  </TabPanel>
  <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
    Item Three
  </TabPanel>
  <Box>
    <Button onClick={submittab}>Submit</Button>
  </Box>
</Box>
```

As mentioned, there are 2 child components with some textfields in it.

What I am trying to achieve is to read the child data in parent and submit it to an API as a single object.

Please help

Below the Sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-shadow-u2icz1?file=/demo.tsx:1233-1962

Please note I am working in typescript

Here is my child component1

```
import { FormLabel, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import react, { useState } from "react";

function Child1() {
  const clientObj = {
    user: {
      name: "",
      age: ""
    }
  };
  const [client, setClient] = useState(clientObj);

  const handlechange = (event: { target: { name: any; value: any } }) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setClient((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      context: {
        ...prevState.user,
        [name]: value
      }
    }));
  };
  return (
    <>
      <FormLabel>Name</FormLabel>
      <TextField
        name="name"
        id="text-id"
        value={client.user.name}
        onChange={handlechange}
      />
      <FormLabel>Age</FormLabel>
      <TextField
        name="name"
        id="text-id"
        value={client.user.name}
        onChange={handlechange}
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Child1;
```

Comment: move the state up into the parent

Comment: You can use ref or a callback

Answer (score 1):

You could use a state in your parent component that will be passed as props to your children, so that they can use the parent's update state function.

Parent code:

```
const [state, setState] = useState()

<Child parentState={{state, setState}} />
```

Children code:

```
export function Child({parentState}) {
  const {parentStateValue, setParentState} = parentState
  const childTitle = 'Acme'
  return <button onClick={setParentState(e => {...e, childTitle })} >childTitle</button>

}
```

the ideal would be to provide keys to your children so that you can manage each of their data independently in the state.

Comment: But a bit confused.. There is no button click or any submit happens inside the child component since its just one tab panel among many and the submit only happens at parent level.

Comment: Do you have inputs inside? Because you can also watch the onchange event

Comment: Could you please check my sandbox link

Comment: from what I see,  you dont have to have an internal state in your child because it will already consume the parent state